# why i cannot run screen command on openshift?

Tags: permissions, gnu-screen, openshift-online-2

i am using redhat openshift, and find some problems now:

**a) why default screen can not support path which contains too much characters**

```
[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> which screen
/usr/bin/screen
[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> screen -S l
LoginName too long - sorry.

[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> screen -S l
LoginName too long - sorry.


[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> ls
app-root  git  jbosseap-6.0  xxname
[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> cd jbosseap-6.0/jbosseap-6.0/tools/bin/
[xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com bin]\> ls
screen  screen-4.1.0  screen-4.1.0.old  screen.old  tmux
```

b) **why i have not priviledge to access /dev/pts/0?**

```
    [xxname-xxname.rhcloud.com bin]\> ./screen-4.1.0 -S l
    Cannot access '/dev/pts/0': Permission denied
```

more details:

```
[xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> ls / -l
ls: cannot access /cgroup: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /lost+found: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /boot: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /net: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /misc: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /root: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home: Permission denied
total 76
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root                             root  4096 Sep  6 16:02 bin
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? boot
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? cgroup
drwxr-xr-x.  17 root                             root  3540 Sep  6 13:47 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 103 root                             root 12288 Sep  7 00:47 etc
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? home
dr-xr-xr-x.  12 root                             root  4096 Sep  6 13:23 lib
dr-xr-xr-x.   9 root                             root 12288 Sep  6 16:02 lib64
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root                             root  4096 Jun 28  2011 media
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? misc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root                             root  4096 Jun 28  2011 mnt
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? net
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root                             root  4096 Sep  6 11:55 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 193 root                             root     0 Sep  6 13:46 proc
d??????????   ? ?                                ?        ?            ? root
drwxrwxrwt.   2 e13f3da3651c44758b254e5bc7bbdddb root  4096 Sep  6 17:13 sandbox
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root                             root 12288 Sep  6 16:02 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   7 root                             root     0 Sep  6 13:46 selinux
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root                             root  4096 Jun 28  2011 srv
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root                             root     0 Sep  6 13:46 sys
drwxrwxrwt.   3 e13f3da3651c44758b254e5bc7bbdddb root  4096 Sep  7 00:51 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root                             root  4096 Sep  6 11:51 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  22 root                             root  4096 Sep  6 11:43 var
[xxname.rhcloud.com ~]\> ls /dev/pts -l
ls: cannot access /dev/pts: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick google reveals an [old limitation with screen, and also that openshift login names are quite long.](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21653)

Try out [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead for an alternative. It should be available in the Red Hat repositories.

Comment: i have tried tmux, failed either... maybe openshift don't support tmux

Comment: Is it the same error when using tmux?

Comment: no error is shown in fact